# Delete nested object from array in Vue

Tags: ajax, vue.js, axios, vuex

trying to delete a nested object from an array. I've done some research and came across an example similar to mine, [Vue.js Remove a Nested Object from Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40116512/vue-js-remove-a-nested-object-from-array).

However my issue is a slight more complex as I am trying to delete the object with ajax request. Essentially my engagement array contains nested objects of questions

[image]

so here is how I am displaying the list of questions for the engagement

```
<div v-for="question in engagement.questions" :key="question.id">
        <div>
          <div ">
            {{ question.question }}
          </div>
          <div >
            <span>Answered: </span>
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="question.answered">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

this is the button that will delete the question

```
<b-btn  @click="deleteQuestion(engagement, question)">Confirm</b-btn>
```

and this is method that dispatches to the store

```
deleteQuestion(engagement, question) {
      this.$store.dispatch('deleteQuestion', id)
      .then(() => {
        this.$router.push({path: '/engagement/' +this.engagement.id , query: {alert: 'The Question Was Succesfully Deleted'}});
      })
    },
```

and this is the store method

```
deleteQuestion(context, id) {
      axios.delete('/questions/' + id)
      .then(response => {
          context.commit('deleteQuestion', id)
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
      })                
    },
```

Right now my alarm is getting “id is not defined” although I have other variations of this code where I will get a 500 internal server error which makes me think that I am not properly capturing the id of the question so it knows which one to delete…

below is the alarm I am getting in the console. I also did which is what the first arrow is pointing to for the observer

```
console.log(question)
```

[image]

Comment: So what's your exact question?

Comment: Why I am i getting a "id is not defined" alarm. Just realized that part was not included in the question. Sorry about that. read above to see that I added it. @AndreyPopov

Comment: What is the exact and complete error message you are getting? Which file and which file?

Comment: @str, view the added content above

Comment: In the second line of `deleteQuestion(engagement, question) {` you reference `id` which does seem to be defined.

Comment: you are passing `question` on the click function `@click="deleteQuestion(engagement, question)"` which is an object to the delete method `deleteQuestion(context, id) {` which expects an id?

Comment: @Jaya, yeah I see the conflict. But im not sure how to filter down to the id of the question without it telling me that it is not defined. The example I included was someone removing the object but like I said it didnt have to be deleted by ajax where as mine does. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If the question object contains an `id` attribute then simply modify your click to : `@click="deleteQuestion(engagement, question.id)"`

Comment: @Jaya, so i have set the @click like you described and have the ```deleteQuestion``` method set to ```deleteQuestion(engagment, id)``` and I am now getting a 404(not found) alarm.

Comment: I am able to delete the question using postman so I know the backend is working.

Comment: @TJWeems i am afraid I cant help more, you got to debug, to figure out if the question's id is indeed being passed on to the axios method. 404 s on DELETE are returned if **resource is not found** which would mean there is no question with the id that is being passed possibly, check if you are able to delete the exact id that is being passed to your axios method via postman

Answer (score 0):

the issue was that the b-model element that contained the @click="deleteQuestion" was outside of the div that contained the v-for so when I would click on the b-modal button it wasn't grabbing the id of the question. So I moved the b-modal to that div and it worked. Thank you for the help.

```
<div class="card mb-3"  v-for="(question, index) in engagement.questions" :key="index">
        <div class="card-header">
          <div class="h6 m-0 justify-content-between d-flex">
            <router-link class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-3" to="#" ><i class="far fa-edit mr-2"></i>Edit</router-link> 
            <b-btn class="outline-secondary" size="sm" v-b-modal.myQuestion><i class="fas fa-trash"></i><span class="ml-2">Delete</span></b-btn>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body bg-light d-flex justify-content-between">
          <div class="h4 mr-5 text-left">
            {{ question.question }}
          </div>
          <div class="ml-5 d-flex align-self-center">
            <span class="font-weight-bold mr-2">Answered: </span>
            <input class="mt-2" type="checkbox" v-model="question.answered">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- this is the modal for deleting a question -->
      <b-modal id="myQuestion" ref="myModalQuestion" hide-footer title="Delete Question">
        <div class="d-block text-left">
          <h5>Are you sure you want to delete question?</h5>
          <br>
          <p><strong>*Warning:</strong> Can not be undone once deleted.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex">
          <b-btn class="mt-3" variant="danger" @click="hideModal">Cancel</b-btn>
          <b-btn class="mt-3 ml-auto" variant="outline-success" @click="deleteQuestion(engagement, question.id)">Confirm</b-btn>
        </div>
      </b-modal>

      </div>
```